# Unexpected result on mov for same variable x86

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, disassembly

I am debugging some C code in GDB, and have disassembled it into x86 code. Here is the snippet

[image]
*Note that for understanding, I have written the next command in the console - the next command is mov 0x10(%rdx), %rdx`*

The way I understand memory referencing modes, for  `mov 0x10(%rdx), %rdx`, we first take the value in `%rdx` which is `0x604300`, add `0x10` to it which gives us `0x604310`. Now THIS is the memory location we should look at for the value we want. Now if we look inside `0x604310`,  we see the answer is `d32` or `0x20`. Now, we move this value to `%rdx`.

However, after executing this command and moving to the next line, I print the value of $rdx and it is `d6308640` or `0x604320`.

How is this possible? Is my understanding flawed ? I am clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` command only dumped 1 byte, but your `mov` instruction loaded 8 bytes.  The low byte is `0x20`, because x86 is little-endian.  (Your manual address calculation is correct).

Use `help x` to see what modifiers you can use for different sizes, and to dump multiple elements.

When you use `print $rdx`, that's *decimal* not hex.  It's a coincidence that the low 2 digits are `40` which is similar-looking to `0x20`.  (But you already figured that out, and yes the hex representation does end in `0x20`).

Use `p /x $rdx` to print reg values in hex.  Or use `layout reg` to use TUI mode with disassembly and register "windows" inside the terminal.

Also I'd suggest `si` (to step instructions) instead of `ni` which steps over calls.  But either are fine if you know what they do, as long as you avoid `n` and `s` to step by C source line when you meant to step by instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the explnanation. I would like to clarify a few things before I accept the answer. So when I do `mov 0x10(%rdx), %rdx` I am essentially moving bytes from memory location 0x604310 through 0x604318 (8 bytes) into the register %rdx. Now,  since 0x604310 has value 0x32, it is present at the bottom end of my register, which is accesible by `x $dl`. The reason I got all the additional stuff is because the memory location following 0x604310 were not empty. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @tsaebeht: We'd normally write that address range as `[0x604310, 0x604317]` 
using inclusive ranges.  The byte at address `0x604318` is in the *next* aligned qword and *not* part of what you load.  The low byte at address `0x604310` has value `0x20` or `32`, not `0x32`.  In GDB you'd show the low byte of `%rdx` with `p /x $dl`.  (`/x` is a modifier for the print command.  `x $dl` would try to dump memory at address `0x20` and fail.)  But yes I think your *understanding* is correct, the mistakes are just typos / wrong commands :)